# Slither not working with Truffle imports

Tags: truffle, truffle-compile

Currently I have a project that needs slither run against it so I pulled down the docker image for slither as specified in the docs here https://hub.docker.com/r/trailofbits/slither/, then I shared the folder from my computer that I needed to run slither against by running the docker images. I found the whole project inside the docker image, did a solc-select to the version of solidity I am using, ran slither against the contracts folder and received the following error:

```
ERROR:root:None
ERROR:root:Error in contracts/
ERROR:root:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ethsec/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/crytic_compile/platform/solc.py", line 367, in _run_solc
    ret = json.loads(stdout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ethsec/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/slither/__main__.py", line 693, in main_impl
    ) = process_all(filename, args, detector_classes, printer_classes)
  File "/home/ethsec/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/slither/__main__.py", line 68, in process_all
    compilations = compile_all(target, **vars(args))
  File "/home/ethsec/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/crytic_compile/crytic_compile.py", line 1041, in compile_all
    compilations.append(CryticCompile(filename, **kwargs))
  File "/home/ethsec/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/crytic_compile/crytic_compile.py", line 124, in __init__
    self._compile(**kwargs)
  File "/home/ethsec/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/crytic_compile/crytic_compile.py", line 931, in _compile
    self._platform.compile(self, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ethsec/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/crytic_compile/platform/solc.py", line 156, in compile
    force_legacy_json=force_legacy_json,
  File "/home/ethsec/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/crytic_compile/platform/solc.py", line 371, in _run_solc
    raise InvalidCompilation(f"Invalid solc compilation {stderr}")
crytic_compile.platform.exceptions.InvalidCompilation: Invalid solc compilation Error: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts-ethereum-package/contracts/Initializable.sol" not found: File not found.

Error: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts-ethereum-package/contracts/utils/ReentrancyGuard.sol" not found: File not found.
```

This seems to be an issue with running slither against files imported by truffle.

I ran slither using truffle as a framework like this:

`slither contracts/ --compile-force-framework truffle@5.1.45`

And I will still receive the same import issue as before.

I have also ran slither like this and it gives the exact same error:

`slither contracts/  --truffle-version  truffle@5.1.45`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: would also enjoy an answer..have you found one?

Answer (score 2):

From root directory of your project :"Your contract should bee in contracts/yourcontractshere.sol"

slither contracts/WeakToken.sol --solc-remaps @openzeppelin/=$(pwd)/node_modules/@openzeppelin/

Answer (score 0):

CD into the folder of your truffle and execute this command in the terminal or cmd

```
slither . --filter-paths "@openzepellin/"
```

@n00bC0der

Answer (score 0):

```
slither . --solc-remaps '@openzeppelin=node_modules/@openzeppelin'
```

this tells slither that if it sees import "@openzeppelin", it should visit `node_modules/@openzeppelin` directory.